# How to delete/download files from the firebase dashboard that were uploaded using the firebase-admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have uploaded files using the admin-sdk for firebase but it appears I cannot download/delete them using the firebase dashboard. This isn't necessarily a problem as I won't be managing my files this way but it does seem odd.

```
// Initialization
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';
const serviceAccount = require('../firebase_creds');
firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://my-databse.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: 'gs://my-bucket.appspot.com'
});

export const uploadImages = async () => {
  const bucket = firebase.storage().bucket();
  try {
    const file = await bucket.upload('./images/1-Website.jpg', {
      public: true,
      destination: `12345/displayPicture/1-Website.jpg`
    });
    console.log(file);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console -> Storage -> Browser. You should see your bucket there.

Comment: Yeah I can see it all there and have full access to download, view, delete etc but when I am using the firebase dashboard all I can do is list the files. Seems to me it's  not uploading with the correct permissions or ACL.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing in `predefinedAcl: 'bucketOwnerFullControl'` to the upload options fixes this issue. As usual the firebase documentation is very vague and does't mention this anywhere.

Comment: Joe can you show how you are using this and the changes to your code?

Comment: What roles does the firebase credentials that you were using have? Your solution makes sense, but then again it does not.

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK just wraps the underlying Cloud Storage SDK (@google-cloud/storage).  If you want comprehensive documentation, use the Cloud docs instead of the Firebase docs.

Comment: @DougStevenson -  My comment is that the solution does not make sense to me. If the project owner is creating the object thru Firebase, why does this ACL need to be specified? The owner should still have all permissions even for an object created public. The issue is that by assigning bucketOwnerFullControl, public access is removed. This solves one problem but creates another. publicRead grants OWNER permission so bucketOwnerFullControl should not be required. I am misising something and that is why I am following this thread.

Comment: @JohnHanley It turns out that by using `public: true` is just an alias for a predefined ACL which looks like `predefinedAcl: publicRead` So it was completely changing the the bucket ACL to something else which firebase wasn't picking it up which would explain why I could see it in the bucket and view the file but not delete it.

Comment: That is what I found and I posted an answer with the exact details of what is happening to the ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this problem in Google documentation.

Short summary: "after you apply the predefined ACL publicRead to the object, you lose OWNER permission and thus no longer can access the object ACL"

> Caution: By applying a predefined ACL to an existing bucket or object,
>   you completely replace the existing bucket or object ACL with the
>   predefined ACL. This change might cause you to lose access to the
>   bucket or object ACL in some cases. For example, if you are in the
>   project owners group but are not the owner of an object with
>   projectPrivate ACL, then after you apply the predefined ACL publicRead
>   to the object, you lose OWNER permission and thus no longer can access
>   the object ACL. If this occurs, you can use the Cloud IAM role
>   storage.objectAdmin so that you have the permission necessary to
>   update the object's ACL and correct the change.

[Predefined ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#predefined-acl)